# SSIS Merge returns few rows

Tags: merge, ssis

My client has sent two files.  A person may be listed in each or both.  I only need one of the records, and in a derived column, I'll want to mark "Both" if they're in both.

I am a beginner, so I thought merge would be a good option as Merge Join didn't seem to fit the bill after trying it out.

My issue is that I have 1,810 and 1,646 rows between the two files.  I only get 343 resulting rows.  I'm guessing that Merge is only giving me the overlap, but I want all of the names so I can use ROW_NUMBER()  to sort out the duplicates.

Am I not choosing the right tool for the job?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a 'Merge' task I think you might want to use a 'Union All' task to combine both files in the data flow.  Then you could use a 'Sort' task to sort by person and check the box in the 'Sort' task labeled 'Remove rows with duplicate sort values' to remove all duplicates.